# How do I turn off Framer Motion animations in mobile view?

Tags: reactjs, framer-motion

I am trying to create a React website using Framer Motion, the problem is that my animation looks good in desktop view, but not really in mobile. Now I want to disable the animation. How do I do this?

Answer (score 11):

Without knowing further details, I would recommend using **Variants** for this.
Inside your functional component, create a variable that checks for mobile devices. Then, only fill the variants if this variable is false.
Note that it doesn't work when you resize the page. The component must get rerendered.

[I've created a codesandbox for you to try it out!](https://codesandbox.io/s/framer-motion-stackoverflow-q1-yigvv?file=/src/App.js)

For further information on **Variants**, [check this course](https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PL4cUxeGkcC9iHDnQfTHEVVceOEBsOf07i)

Comment: Yes, this is what I've been looking for! Appreciate it mate!

Comment: On SO, you should mark an answer as accepted if it fits your needs. Just click on the tick symbol.

Comment: Thanks for the reminder, totally forgot about it.

Answer (score 4):

Another simple way I just did myself when this exact question came up. Below we are using a **ternary operatory** to generate a object which we then spread using the **spread syntax**

```
const attributes = isMobile ? {
    drag: "x",
    dragConstraints: { left: 0, right: 0 },
    animate: { x: myVariable },
    onDragEnd: myFunction
} : { onMouseOver, onMouseLeave };

<motion.div {...attributes}> {/* stuff */} </motion.div>
```

As you can see I want onMouseEnter & onMouseLeave on desktop with no animations. On mobile I want the opposite. This is working of me perfectly.
Hope this helps too.

Daniel

Answer (score 2):

This is how we've done it:

```
import {
  type ForwardRefComponent,
  type HTMLMotionProps,
  motion as Motion,
} from 'framer-motion';
import { forwardRef } from 'react';

const ReducedMotionDiv: ForwardRefComponent<
  HTMLDivElement,
  HTMLMotionProps<'div'>
> = forwardRef((props, ref) => {
  const newProps = {
    ...props,
    animate: undefined,
    initial: undefined,
    transition: undefined,
    variants: undefined,
    whileDrag: undefined,
    whileFocus: undefined,
    whileHover: undefined,
    whileInView: undefined,
    whileTap: undefined,
  };

  return <Motion.div {...newProps} ref={ref} />;
});

export const motion = new Proxy(Motion, {
  get: (target, key) => {
    if (key === 'div') {
      return ReducedMotionDiv;
    }

    // @ts-expect-error - This is a proxy, so we can't be sure what the key is.
    return target[key];
  },
});

export {
  AnimatePresence,
  type Variants,
  type HTMLMotionProps,
  type MotionProps,
  type TargetAndTransition,
  type Transition,
  type Spring,
} from 'framer-motion';
```

Same principle as other answers, just complete example.